# Re-arrange string contents

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a string like: `(10.00+Age)power2`

I want to change the string to: `power(10.00+Age,2)`

How is this possible with sql server 2008.?

Comment: It would help if you could give some more examples and make it clear which parts of the string change and which are always the same. Without that information it's not easy to give a definite answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression reconstructs your strings as described:

```
'power' + replace(my_column, ')power', ',') + ')'
```

[See SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74044/1)

Answer (score 0):

If the string is always in the format you show, you could do a simple replace

```
replace("(10+Age)power2",")power2",",2)")
```

Updated

```
DECLARE @ans VARCHAR(200)
SET @ans = 'power'+replace('(10+Age)power2',')power2',',2)')
```

Comment: This will fail because you have double quotes instead of single quotes, and even with them it will give the wrong result because it doesn't 'move' `power` to the start of the string.

Comment: Actually, the OP changed the question after my response.   You are correct that the default delimiter for SQL is the single quote, but you can change it to the double quote character as well.   Forgot we do that on some of our servers...